# Eigenvalues of $d/dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $d/dx:C^\infty(\mathbf{R})\rightarrow C^\infty(\mathbf{R})$ (both as real vector spaces). I want to find its eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors. Every $\lambda\in\mathbf{R}$ is an eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector $\exp(\lambda x$) (so that the eigenspace belonging to $\lambda$ is one-dimensional, generated by $\exp(\lambda x)$, is this true?). Are these *all*?

Comment: Based on your comments on the answers at the moment, I interpret this question as: "Why are $f(x)=C\exp(\lambda x),\,C\in\mathbb{R}$ the only solutions to the differential equation $f'=\lambda f$?" Am I right?

Comment: Your post has been flagged for moderation. You've cannibalized two of your posts beyond recognition within minutes. I have asked that your account be suspended.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $\Phi:=\frac{d}{dx}$ and $f$ an eigenvector associated to $\lambda$ then
$$\Phi(f)=\lambda f\iff f'=\lambda f\iff f(x)=ce^{\lambda x},\; c\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$$
so the eigenspace associated to $\lambda$ is $$\operatorname{span}(x\mapsto e^{\lambda x})$$
is a one dimensional subspace of $ C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.